# How to keep paypal mini cart (paypal labs) on top

Tags: html, css, paypal

I have integrated paypal mini-cart into my website but for some reason it is not on top, I have changed the z-index to as high as possible and still no result.

It seems to be over everything except the text in the navigation bar (e.g HOME etc) and when the class=current it seems to override it too.

Any help on how to solve this would be hugely appreciated!

When you add an option to cart then resize the window so the cart overlaps the navigation area

Comment: DO you have an example - a jsfiddle would help

Comment: Yes, sorry - Please now check the description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the following in your stylesheet:

```
ul#navigation {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 30;
  margin-top: 2px;
  margin-right: 117px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Your `z-index` is placing the menu over the paypal cart. Removing this z-index will solve your issues. Well it did at least for me disabling the property in my Chrome debugger.

Comment: Huge thanks, I have noticed a problem with that - It goes benieth the slider on the homepage but I am sure I can sort that by doing the same for that area.

Comment: The real solution would be to set proper Z-index numbers. Something i do is use increments of 10, hence, base layers z-index:0, then menus for example: z-index: 10; , then next thing 20 etc.. this is easier than if you had 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10  as if you realised you missed something you would have alot of z-indexes to change. In my way you can slot upto 9 things without having a knock on impact.

Comment: Thanks for the extra tip :) I will use that in future!